# My BFS code is only showing the direct paths from source to destination, but not all possible paths

Tags: c, path, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I want to print all possible paths from a given source and destination. But in my BFS code, it only shows the two paths, not the multiple path. For a directed graph where n = 4, edge = 6, given,

```
1-2
1-3
1-5
5-3
5-4
3-4
3-2
```

It should've printed 3 paths:

```
1-5-4
1-3-4
1-5-3-4
```

But it only shows this two paths

```
1-3-4
1-5-4
```

This is my sample code for finding the src to destination path

```
#include <stdio.h>

int queue1[100], state[100], parent[100];
int front = 0, rear = -1, maxSize = 100;
int count = 0;
int initial = 1, waiting = 2, visited = 3;
int n, e;
int adj[100][100];

bool isEmpty()
{
    return count == 0;

}
bool isFull()
{
    return count == maxSize;
}
void enqueue(int val)
{
    if (!isFull())
    {
        if (rear == maxSize - 1)
        {
            rear = -1;
        }
        rear++;
        queue1[rear] = val;
        count++;
    }
}
int dequeue()
{
    int val = queue1[front];
    front++;

    if (front == maxSize)
    {
        front = 0;
    }
    count--;
    return val;
}
void BFS_Traversal(int src, int des)
{
    int done = 0;
    enqueue(src);
    state[src] = waiting;
    parent[src] = -1;

    printf("path ");

    while (!isEmpty() && done == 0)
    {

        src = dequeue();
        // printf("%d ",src);
        state[src] = visited;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            if (adj[src][i] == 1 && state[i] == initial)
            {
                enqueue(i);
                state[i] = waiting;
                parent[i] = src;
                if (i == des)
                {
                    state[i] = initial;
                    int k = des;

                    do
                    {
                        printf("%d ", k);
                        k = parent[k];
                    } while (k != -1);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
int main()
{
    int src, start, end, des;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &e);

    for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &start, &end);
        adj[start][end] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        state[i] = initial;
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        parent[k] = -1;
    }

    scanf("%d%d", &src, &des);
    BFS_Traversal(src, des);
}
```

As, you can see 1-5-3-4 path is not showing because they are already visited. How should I modify this code to print all possible paths?

Comment: Are `visited`, `waiting` and `initial` variables? I cannot find their definition!

Comment: @kiner_shah yah, i've updated the code. Check now

Comment: Could you please provide a compilable code ? `enqueue/dequeue` function are missing, `adj` undeclared, `n` and `e` as well.

Comment: @Martin edited, check now